# How to change time zone in Apps Script file - New Editor

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I change the time zone in the NEW apps script editor? I have been able to find google documentation describing the process for the LEGACY editor (File > Project Properties > Info > Time zone). However, I see no such menu or option in the new editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very frustrating problem for a couple reasons. First, google's documentation on this is still for the legacy editor. Second, there are very few menu / navigation options in the new script editor. I finally figured this out and wanted to share incase anyone else has this issue.

In the NEW apps script editor, go to Project Settings (the gear icon) and check the box that says "Show 'appsscript.json' manifest file in editor." Navigate back to the editor tab, and you will notice a new file in your files list that is called appsscript.json. Open this file and you will see a key-value pair for "timeZone." You can change this to whatever timezone you would like, and that changes it for the apps script file.